# Issue while promoting 2GP beta package to Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, 2gp

We are facing one issue while promoting the 2gp beta package to managed package.

Please consider the following scenario.

1. Created a package with command -
   sfdx force:package:version:create -p s_converse7 -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v atharva@abc.com.

While promoting the beta package I am getting this error
Code coverage has not been run for this version. Code coverage must be run during version creation and meet the minimum coverage requirement to promote the version

2. So created a package with the command
   sfdx force:package:version:create -c -p s_converse7 -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v atharva@abc.com
   Devhub user - atharva@abc.com

-c flag denotes that test cases should be run while package creation is taking place.

3. Test cases are getting run but they are failing because the dev hub user (atharva@abc.com) does not have the permission to the objects on which query has been made from our application in test cases.
4. In our package the user (in this case a devhub user - atharva@abc.com) who runs the test case needs a permission set (Admin permission set) to get access to the objects so that test cases will run. As our code is not deployed on the dev hub, we won’t be able to assign the permission set. Also, we can not deploy the code on the dev hub as the dev hub does not have a namespace that is required for our code.
5. Here we are recommended to use system.runas in our test case and assign the permission set to dynamically created user.
   It looks very heavy task as our application has a lot of test cases and making changes to them would tedious task for us.

Please suggest any other way to solve this.

Comment: I think the only choice is option 5.

Comment: You can also consider using [Unpackage Metadata for Package Version Creation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm) with option 5. That probably makes the job much easier.